# How can one remove items from a vector that exceed a count?

Tags: r, statistics

Apologies if I ask this incorrectly, but I am new to R. Say I have a vector X like this:

```
Sam
George
George
Suzzy
Suzzy
Suzzy
Leo
```

What I'd like is to be able to get a vector that contains names that only appear twice, but keep the amount of times they occur in the original vector. Here is an example of what the psuedocode would look like:

```
x <- x[sum x.uniquecount() >=2]
```

And the final result:

```
George
George
Suzzy
Suzzy
Suzzy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 vec <- scan(what="")
1: Sam
2: George
3: George
4: Suzzy
5: Suzzy
6: Suzzy
7: Leo
8: 
Read 7 items


vec[ vec %in% names(table(vec))[table(vec) >= 2] ]
[1] "George" "George" "Suzzy"  "Suzzy"  "Suzzy"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I have to apologize, but I got the output incorrect. I've edited the question. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- read.table(text = "Sam
George
George
Suzzy
Suzzy
Suzzy
Leo")

n <- ave(as.numeric(df$V1), df$V1, FUN = length)

df[n > 1, ]

# [1] George George Suzzy  Suzzy  Suzzy
```